# $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors but there is no $

Tags: r, shiny

I'm getting an error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

However, I don't have a $ sign in my server:

```
  output[["r_graph"]] <- renderImage({
    r <- reddit_urls(search_terms = input[["reddit1"]], subreddit = input[["reddit2"]], page_threshold = 20, sort_by = "new")%>%
      mutate(date = as.Date(date, "%d-%m-%y"))
    
    min_date <- as.Date(Sys.time()) - 14
    max_date <- as.Date(Sys.time())
    
    reddit <- r %>% filter(date >=min_date  & date <=max_date)
    
    reddit_df <-
      reddit %>%
      group_by(date) %>%
      summarise(Total = sum(num_comments))
    
    myplot <- ggplot(reddit_df, aes(x=date, y=Total)) + 
      geom_point(aes(size=3)) 
    
    animateplot <- myplot + transition_time(date) +
      shadow_mark() + xlab("Date") + ylab("Occurences on Reddit")
    
    animate(animateplot)
  })
```

I changed output$r_graph, input$reddit1, input$reddit2 into the above values so I have no more $ signs. Any tips?

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example. It's hard to know what the problem is without it.

Comment: First step: use traceback() and find out which function throws the error (probably because it gets passed an object with the wrong class).

Comment: This means you have an improper call to some function - parameters need to be specified.  Also, it is possible that there is conflict in some functions.  For example, `summarise()` function is present in mutliple packages, and therefore, you can specifiy it as `dplyr::summarise()` if you want to use it from dplyr.  Without a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is hard to know where the problem is - as someone already stated.